Strange Bluetooth Behavior on Windows 10 19045 using .NET 4.8.1
I am seeing a very odd bug occurring in my application. Essentially I have an iPad that sends a text string over to my Windows PC. This seems to work very consistently with minimal issues.
The code for this entire system is in C#:
static GattCharacteristicsResult gattCharacteristic;

private GattCharacteristicProperties properties;
private GattCharacteristic characteristic;

private IReadOnlyList<GattDeviceService> services;
private ulong LEdevice = 0;
private BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice;
private BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher;
    
// TopazController _topazController = new TopazController();
    
public async Task BackgroundBluetooth()
{ 
        watcher = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
        watcher.Received += Watcher_Received;
        watcher.AllowExtendedAdvertisements = true;
        watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Active;
        watcher.Start();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Background bluetooth starting...");

        while (true)
        {
            if (LEdevice == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            else
            {
                if (bleDevice != null)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("BLE is already connected");
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    continue;
                }
                
                /* This hangs for some reason if Topaz Object is created ?? */
                Console.WriteLine("Start");
                bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(LEdevice);
                Console.WriteLine("Stop");
                
                var serviceID = new Guid("e20a39f4-73f5-4bc4-a12f-17d1ad07a961");
                var result = await bleDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(serviceID);
        
                if (result?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to Service");
                    services = result.Services;
                    gattCharacteristic = await services[0].GetCharacteristicsAsync();
                    if (gattCharacteristic.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Characteristic");
                        characteristic = gattCharacteristic.Characteristics[0];
                        characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;
        
                        properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
        
                        if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Notify Found");
                            GattCommunicationStatus status =
                                await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                                    GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
                            if (status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Gatt Communication Success");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + gattCharacteristic.Status);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + result.Status);
                }
            }
        }
}
    
void Characteristic_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(args.CharacteristicValue);
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        reader.ByteOrder = ByteOrder.LittleEndian;
        var value = reader.ReadString(args.CharacteristicValue.Length);

        Console.WriteLine(value);

       // ProcessCommand(value);
}
    
void Watcher_Received(BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
{
        foreach (var uuid in args.Advertisement.ServiceUuids)
        {
            if (uuid.ToString() == "e20a39f4-73f5-4bc4-a12f-17d1ad07a961")
            {
                if (LEdevice == 0)
                {
                    LEdevice = args.BluetoothAddress;
                }
            }
        }
}

This is where things begin to get very strange. I have a Topaz Reader the model is TF-LBK4640 HSB-R, it's a finger print reader and signature pad in one.
I thought that I want to try and control this Topaz Pad through some Bluetooth commands and see what happens. I started sending JUST some string messages, they work with no issue.
So then I went ahead and created a Topaz Object and tried to do some super basic functionality. Suddenly the Bluetooth system completely broke. I began slowly removing all this basic functionality until I found the culprit. It's creating this Topaz Object that breaks the Bluetooth system
TopazController _topazController = new TopazController();

This took some tracking down. If I have this object creation ANYWHERE in the application, the bluetooth breaks. And it breaks exactly at this code point. This function will never return, it hangs indefinitely.
bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(LEdevice)

I'm very confused at how these two things can even be correlated? How does this object even effect the Bluetooth system?
I'm looking for guidance in how to tackle this problem, I've done some research online and I saw a bug related to a very old Windows 10 build having issues with this function hanging. I went ahead and implemented the registry fixes and still the problem persists.
What on earth could cause these two devices to conflict like this? Any assistance will be greatly appreciated!!
Also some technical information that might be helpful:

.NET 4.8.1
Windows UWP
Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0

Has anyone had this before? Is this a Windows 10 issue?

Please try to collect bluetooth log using busiotools. Besides, what is the TopazController class? Is it a custom class or a third-party library class?
